# PhoneGap Build Difficulty

Tags: ios, debugging, cordova, cross-platform

I'm getting started with PhoneGap on iOS and not having much luck. My app is stuck on the splash screen and nothing is shown in Phoegap Build's console.

The screenshot at https://i.stack.imgur.com/gavIs.png shows both my file structure and skeleton code. The only thing I see from the app is the alert of '1' called from body's onload event. Nothing else is shown. Is there a glaring mistake which is killing the app?

Comment: include 
 document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
Also try with including correct cordova file.(<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-x.x.x.js"></script>
)

Comment: On top of what Nijil said, you have to load jQuery before you load Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

alert(1) is coming from javaScript and you has nothing to do with phonegap.

You would want to make sure that your code directory has the necessary API's that call Phonegap code. It would look like something below:

```
package com.news.newsfinder;

import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;




public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }


}
```

You must have cordova.jar in your build path and cordova.js in your js directory.

Then your javascript code to call phonegap API's can become something like this.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {
        checkConnection();
    }


function checkConnection() {
    //code to check what type of internet connection a device is using, wifi, 2G, 3G...
 }
```

The above code which has  a package `com.news.newsfinder`  will make an APP in play store like below:

[**http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.news.newsfinder**](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.news.newsfinder)